# ionic select list not working on phone

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Is anyone else struggling getting select lists to work from handsets?
This works on a desktop but doesnt from handsets in safari, (i tried ios).
http://goo.gl/e5ePRh

How do you get select lists to work in ionic/angularjs/phonegap ?

Answer (score 0):

You link for ionic.bundle not working. If you try with this: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionic/1.0.0/js/ionic.bundle.js
"select" will work corectly.

Hope it will help :)

Comment: for me it not help. Have use   Ionic, v1.1.0-nightly-1583 and it still not working